Error al descargar archivo PDF en Angular
Tengo una aplicación que utiliza Angular para la parte front, y SpringBoot para la parte back. Me gustaría que el cliente, además de poder ver todas las solicitudes que ha realizado, pudiera descargar el fichero inicial que ha adjuntado en la solicitud. Del cuál, se guarda el nombre y ruta en la BBDD.
Controlador del back:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/solicitudes")
public class SolicitudController {

    @Autowired
    private SolicitudService solicitudService;

    @Autowired
    private EmailService emailService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<SolicitudRequest> crearSolicitud(
            @RequestParam("fechaSolicitud") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime fechaSolicitud,
            @RequestParam("usuario") Long usuario,
            @RequestParam("tipoDia") TipoDia tipoDia,
            @RequestParam("nombreArchivo") String nombreArchivo,
            @RequestParam("archivoAdjunto") MultipartFile archivoAdjunto) throws Exception {
        try {
            if (fechaSolicitud == null || usuario == null || tipoDia == null || nombreArchivo == null
                    || archivoAdjunto == null) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }

            System.out.println("Llamada al servicio para crear la solicitud.");

            Solicitud nuevaSolicitud = solicitudService.crearSolicitud(fechaSolicitud, usuario,
                    tipoDia, nombreArchivo, archivoAdjunto);

            // System.out.println("Solicitud creada correctamente: " + nuevaSolicitud);
            if (nuevaSolicitud != null) {
                emailService.enviarCorreo(StaticData.DESTINATARIO, StaticData.ASUNTO_NUEVA_SOLICITUD,
                        StaticData.getMensajeConfirmacion());
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        } catch (SolicitudException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Mensaje de error: " + e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> manejarSolicitud(@RequestParam(required = false) Long id,
            @RequestParam(value = "descargar", required = false) Boolean descargar,
            @RequestParam(value = "idUsuario", required = false) Long idUsuario) {
        if (id != null && descargar != null && descargar) {
            return descargarArchivo(id);
        } else if (idUsuario != null) {
            return obtenerSolicitud(idUsuario);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Parámetros incorrectos");
        }
    }

    private ResponseEntity<?> obtenerSolicitud(Long idUsuario) {
        System.out.println("Entrando al método para obtener solicitudes: ");
        try {
            Usuario usuario = userService.findById(idUsuario);
            if (usuario == null) {
                throw new Exception("El usuario no existe");
            }

            List<Solicitud> solicitudes = solicitudService.findAllById(idUsuario);
            if (solicitudes != null && !solicitudes.isEmpty()) {
                return ResponseEntity.ok().body(solicitudes);
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Mensaje de error: " + e.getMessage());
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }

    private ResponseEntity<Resource> descargarArchivo(Long id) {
        Solicitud solicitud = solicitudService.findById(id);
        if (solicitud == null || solicitud.getRutaAString() == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }

        Path rutaArchivo = Paths.get(solicitud.getRutaAString());
        UrlResource recurso;
        try {
            recurso = new UrlResource(rutaArchivo.toUri());
            if (!recurso.exists() || !recurso.isReadable()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("No se puede leer el archivo: " + solicitud.getRutaAString());
            }

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);

            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .headers(headers)
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + recurso.getFilename() + "\"")
                    .body(recurso);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }

Código del front:
Servicio:
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SolicitudService {
  private url: string = '/api/solicitudes'; // solicitud a la API

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getSolicitudesPorUsuario(idUsuario: number): Observable<Solicitud[]> {
    const urlUsuario = `${this.url}?idUsuario=${idUsuario}`;
    return this.http.get<Solicitud[]>(urlUsuario).pipe(
      tap((data: any) => console.log(`Solicitudes para el usuario ${idUsuario} recibidas`, data)),
      catchError((error: any) => {
        console.error(`Error al obtener las solicitudes para el usuario ${idUsuario}`);
        throw error;
      })
    );
  }

  manejarSolicitud(id: number, descargar: boolean): Observable<Blob | Solicitud[]> {
    const url = `${this.url}/${id}`;
    if (descargar) {
      return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' });
    } else {
      return this.http.get<Solicitud[]>(url);
    }
  }

  crearSolicitud(solicitud: SolicitudRequest, archivo: File): Observable<Solicitud> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fechaSolicitud', solicitud.fecha_solicitud.toISOString());
    formData.append('usuario', (solicitud.usuario ?? '').toString());
    formData.append('tipoDia', solicitud.tipoDia);
    formData.append('nombreArchivo', solicitud.nombreArchivo);
    formData.append('archivoAdjunto', archivo, archivo.name);

    return this.http.post<Solicitud>(this.url, formData);
  }

Función del componente:
descargarArchivo(idSolicitud: number): void {
    this.solicitudService.manejarSolicitud(idSolicitud, true).subscribe(response => {
      if (response instanceof Blob) {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = `Solicitud${idSolicitud}.pdf`;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      } else {
        this.solicitudes = response;
        this.solicitudes.forEach(solicitud => {
        });
      }
    }, error => {
      console.error('Error al procesar la solicitud:', error);
    });
  }

Trozo de html:
 <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success"(click)="descargarArchivo(solicitud.id)">Inicial</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Firmado</button>

La idea es que al hacer click en el botón se descargue el fichero PDF. Cuando se descarga el fichero, ninguna aplicación me lo abre porque el contenido se muestra en un formato incorrecto. Es decir, analizando las cabeceras de la petición y la respuesta en la consola del navegador, me encuentro con esto:
Cabeceras de la respuesta:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/html
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Tue, 21 May 2024 10:33:03 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Content-Length: 2318

Cabeceras de la petición:
GET /api/solicitudes/26 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Priority: u=1

Cómo se puede ver, se devuelve un text/html. He probado a hacer la petición desde http://localhost:8080/api/solicitudes/26 y el fichero que se descarga en ese caso, se abre correctamente. No sé cómo puedo solucionarlo ni a qué se puede deber, así qué, agradecería mucho toda ayuda.

Es de esperar que el blob tenga el tipo MIME correcto, pero si no lo tiene, te puedes valer del método slice para corregirlo, por ejemplo, antes de llamar a CreateObjectURL podrías hacer response = response.slice(0, response.size, "application/pdf");  Solo tener en cuenta que, momentaneamente, esto duplicará el consumo de memoria.

Muchísimas gracias por la sugerencia para la verificación. Al final, cómo seguía dando problemas, he modificado la función de esta forma:  descargarArchivo(idSolicitud: number): void {
const url = http://localhost:8080/api/solicitudes/descargar?id=${idSolicitud};
window.open(url, '_blank');
} para que sea el navegador el que maneje la descarga y de este modo me ha funcionado. Gracias de nuevo por la ayuda!

En tu controlador veo el siguiente método:
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> manejarSolicitud(
           @RequestParam(required = false) Long id,
            @RequestParam(value = "descargar", required = false) Boolean descargar,
            @RequestParam(value = "idUsuario", required = false) Long idUsuario) {
        if (id != null && descargar != null && descargar) {
            return descargarArchivo(id);
        } else if (idUsuario != null) {
            return obtenerSolicitud(idUsuario);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Parámetros incorrectos");
        }
    }

Que si recibe una llamada a "/api/solicitudes" con id como parámetro numérico y con descargar como parámetro booleano con valor true, descargará el fichero, algo como /api/solicitudes?id=4&descargar=true.
Pero tu llamada AJAX hace una llamada GET /api/solicitudes/26:
manejarSolicitud(id: number, descargar: boolean): Observable<Blob | Solicitud[]> {
    const url = `${this.url}/${id}`;
    if (descargar) {
      return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' });
    } else {
      return this.http.get<Solicitud[]>(url);
    }
  }

Por tanto

No manda descargar con valor true como parámetro
No usa un parámetro (@RequestParam) id con el valor 26, más bien usa una @PathVariable que no está declarada en el controlador.


Tienes razón, muchísimas gracias por la observación!
